# variable should not be used in output port connection

Tags: register

I searched random verilog heirarchy to understand how to properly instantiate modules. I found one on https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/design-examples/design-software/verilog/ver_hier.html

I am getting an error saying "variable 'intsig' should not be used in output port connection"

```
module top_ver (q, p, r, out);
input     q, p, r;
output    reg out;
reg     intsig;

bottom1 u1(.a(q), .b(p), .c(intsig));
bottom2 u2(.l(intsig), .m(r), .n(out));

endmodule
```

edit 1

```
module top_ver (q, p, r, out, clk);

input     q, p, r ,clk;
output    reg out;
reg     intsig;
    always@(posedge clk) begin
        bottom1 u1(.a(q), .b(p), .c(intsig));
        bottom2 u2(.l(intsig), .m(r), .n(out));
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 5):

Even if the `c` output of `bottom1` is produced by a flip-flop, in `top_ver` you are not assigning `intsig` in a procedural block (an `always` or `initial` block).

Therefore you must declare `intsig` as a `wire` rather than a `reg`.

Regardless of whether the signal is actually produced by a flip-flop or combinatorial logic, in Verilog you declare a signal as `reg` when you will assign to it in a procedural block (again, `always` or `initial`) and you declare it as `wire` (or one of the variants like `wor` or `wand`) when you are going to assign to it in a combinatorial statement (`assign` or as the output of an instantiated module).

Comment: i tried using an always block so i can have clk as an input. I am getting an error that the bottom1 and bottom2 are not defined.  edit got it. it shouldn't be done inside the always block

Comment: You can't instantiate a module inside an always block. You should declare `intsig` as `wire` instead of `reg`, because you aren't going to assign to it in an always block.